# Корневой каталог в java ee проекте

Tags: java-ee, tomcat

Использую tomcat, никак не могу найти корневой каталог, чтобы прописать путь к файлу. Приходится писать абсолютный, подскажите где он находится.

Comment: абсолютный путь к чему? зачем вам это надо - опишите что пытаетесь сделать и как пытаетесь сделать

Comment: Из текстового файла нужно получать значения и я не мог указать относительный путь к этому файлу в проекте, получалось только через абсолютный начиная с диска С:\\какаятопапка\\какаяпапка\\text.txt и возник вопрос где в проекте находится корневой каталог, чтобы указать путь относительно него, ниже в ответе указали, что корневой каталог находится там, где лежит файл catalina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `tomcat` корневой каталог считается относительно файла `catalina.sh`

Уменя он лежит здесь:

```
/opt/apache-tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
```